# Magento 2: How to Create admin user programmatically using frontend controller

Tags: magento2, admin, frontend

I want to create an admin user programmatically , from the frontend controller my frontend code is:

```
<?php 
namespace Learning\HelloPage\Controller\Account;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
class Add extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{ 
    protected $_userFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $userFactory
       ) 
    {
        $this->_userFactory = $userFactory;
    }

    public function execute(){

        $adminInfo = [
            'username'  => 'killer',
            'firstname' => 'admin',
            'lastname'    => 'admin',
            'email'     => 'me@helloworld.com',
            'password'  =>'hello@123',       
            'interface_locale' => 'en_US',
            'is_active' => 1
        ];

        $userModel = $this->_userFactory->create();
        $userModel->setData($adminInfo);
        $userModel->setRoleId(7);
        try{
           $userModel->save(); 
           echo 'saved';
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

it is giving me this error.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

For the first thing If you are using this `controller` on frontend side then you should extend the `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` class Instead of `Magento\Backend\App\Action`

And you can use below script to create an user for admin

```
use \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory;
use \Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User;

public function __construct(
       ...... 
        UserFactory $userFactory,
        User $userResourceModel,     
        .....
    ) {
        $this->userFactory = $userFactory;
        $this->userResourceModel = $userResourceModel;
    }
```

Now you can use this like,

```
    $model = $this->userFactory->create();        
    $model->setRoleId(7);// change with it 
    $data = array(
        'username' => 'killer',
        'firstname' => 'killer',
        'lastname' => 'killer',
        'email' => 'me@helloworld.com',
        'password' => 'hello@123',
        'is_active' => 1,
        'interface_locale' => ' en_US',
        'role_id' => 7
    );
    $model->setData($data);
    $this->userResourceModel->save($model);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Learning\HelloPage\Controller\Account\Add::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User, none given, called in /var/www/html/magento2/var/generation/Learning/HelloPage/Controller/Account/Add/Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Learning/HelloPage/Controller/Account/Add.php:12 Stack trace: #0

Comment: got this error.

Comment: Try to run di:compile :) @J

Comment: Learning\HelloPage\Controller\Account\Add\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\User\Model\UserFactory)) #2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Learning\\HelloP...', Array) #3 /var/www/html/magen in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Learning/HelloPage/Controller/Account/Add.php on line 12

Comment: again got this error

Comment: Accept the answer If you find it helpful @JayKapoor

Comment: how can i accept if it didnt work

Comment: You just need to run di:compile nothing else, If you don't want to accept then I don't mind :) @JayKapoor

Comment: ok i will run di:conpile cmd

Comment: After creating user using above code, I got error when I edit user role in admin. It says User token not "This user has no tokens." Please let me know the solution if you face the same issue.